# Error while loading shared libraries - libwebsock

Tags: linux, gcc, shared-libraries

Im trying to setup [libwebsock](https://github.com/payden/libwebsock), simple C websocket library. I followed the installation procedure from INSTALL file, everything went fine. Im able to compile test program given in the examples. But when I want to run my executable, wild error appears:

```
./echo: error while loading shared libraries: libwebsock.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I checked /usr/local/lib twice, libwebsock.so.1 exists and is doing very well. I also tried copying the lib to the echo folder (so its placed next to binary), still same error. It's quite funny for me:

```
shadowz@Ubu:~/WebSocket$ ls
echo echo.c echo.cpp libwebsock.so.1
shadowz@Ubu:~/WebSocket$ ./echo
./echo: error while loading shared libraries: libwebsock.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any suggestions? Im running out of ideas...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running `ldconfig` manually (as root) in case it wasn't run during installation of the libs. The shared linker uses a cache to look up shared libraries, and `ldconfig` is needed to update it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, but for a different application (Tecplot 2008) and libXpm.so.4 was missing although **libxpm** seemed to be installed. Turns out I was using a 64-bit OS, and the application was looking for the 32-bit libraries. I'm using Manjaro (Arch linux based) and so installing the following did the trick:

```
sudo pacman -S multilib-devel
sudo pacman -S lib32-libxpm
```